# How to find the maximum value of $12\sin x -9\sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the maximum value of $12\sin x -9\sin^2x$ ;

My approach :

This can be written as $-[(3\sin x -2)^2-4]$.
It means that the function will be maximum when $(3\sin x-2)^2 <4$ due to negative sign outside bracket.

But I am not getting how to proceed from here, please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Where has $4 - y^2$ its maximum? And what is that maximum?

Comment: Different approach could be using the first derivative:$\frac{d}{dx}(12 sin(x)-9 sin^2(x)) = 6 (2-3 sin(x)) cos(x)$

Answer (score 4):

Note
$$ 12\sin x-9\sin^2x=3\sin x(4-3\sin x)\le \left(\frac{3\sin x+(4-3\sin x)}{2}\right)^2=4 $$
and the equal sign holds if and only if $3\sin x=4-3\sin x$ or $\sin x=\frac{2}{3}$.
Thus the max is 4 when $\sin x=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Nice solution Xpaul Using Inequality, But i did not understand bcz $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}$ is applicable when $3\sin ,4-3\sin x>0$ but here $3\sin x $ may be positive or negative, bcz $x$ not given here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
The function $f(x) = 12\sin(x) - 9\sin^2(x)$ has a local maximum wherever

$$0 = f'(x) = 12\cos(x) - 18\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

which is true for $\cos(x) = 0$ or $\sin(x) = \frac{12}{18}$

Since the function is periodic you need to check a few local max points, (but not too many).

Answer (score 1):

You can start by making a perfect square

-9$(sin^2x$-$\frac{4}{3}sinx$)

$\implies$-9$((sinx+\frac{2}{3})^2-(\frac{2}{3})^2)$

$\implies$ 4 - 9$([-1,1]+\frac{2}{3})^2$

$\implies$ 4 - $[0,\frac{5}{9}]$

$\implies$ $[\frac{31}{9},4]$

Therefore, Maximum value=4